# Error When Setting TextView Visibility In Handler

Tags: android

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, and none of the other solutions I found on stackoverflow have solved my problem.

My UI thread has a handler:

```
//Global declarations
private UIHandler mHandler;

class UIHandler extends Handler {
    TextView actionTV, objectTV;

    public UIHandler(TextView t1,TextView t2){
        actionTV = t1;
        objectTV = t2;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // a message is received; update UI text view
        actionTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Throws "CalledFromWrongThreadExc"
        objectTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        System.out.println("Received Message");
    }
}

    //Inside of onCreate()
    actionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diceAction);
    objectText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diceObject);
    mHandler = new UIHandler(actionText,objectText);

    //Inside of onClick
    renderer.rollDice(mHandler);
    actionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    objectText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And the handler receives a message from my openGL rendering thread. The message passes successfully, as I have tested that out.

I am getting a "CalledFromWrongThread" error on the line "action.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)". I thought passing the TextView into the Handler in onCreate() would solve the problem, but it hasn't. If someone can point out where I went wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I create it in OnCreate(), then I pass it to my renderer in rollDice().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question, it appears you must 'invalidate' your textviews after modifying them. [help with Handler class to update UI - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060068/help-with-handler-class-to-update-ui-android)

Also usually ui actions are not done from the handler thread, they are done with a runnable that the handler posts. The runnable would be in the Activity thread. See if these suggestions help, or get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was the best way to go about solving it, but I fixed my error by using the function runOnUiThread(Runnable) in my renderer's thread. Where before I was dispatching a message, I now just call this:

```
            //int flag = myRenderer.CALC_FINISHED;
        mUIView.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ((View) mUIView.findViewById(R.id.diceAction)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((View) mUIView.findViewById(R.id.diceObject)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((View) mUIView.findViewById(R.id.actionLock)).setClickable(true);
                ((View) mUIView.findViewById(R.id.objectLock)).setClickable(true);
            }
        });
        //mHandler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler,flag));
        //mHandler = null;
```